# Parallelizing an associative binary operation

Tags: parallelization, operators

I have an associative binary operation '`.`', which I often use in this sort of way:

```
result = expr1 . expr2 . expr3 . expr4
```

The '`.`' operation is very fast, but the individual subexpressions are often *hard* to compute. So I would like my '`.`' operation to automatically parallelize itself, evaluating each of the separate subexpressions in separate kernels before finally taking the results and actually performing the operation.

How can I achieve this in Mathematica? It seems there are several challenges. One is to prevent the subexpressions evaluating before the '`.`' operation is evaluated.

Comment: Why don't you evaluate the subexpression in parallel first, and perform the `.` only afterwards?  I don't understand why you need to couple these two things.  `Fold[myDot, dotIdentity, Parallelize[{expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4}]]`

Comment: Because I use this everywhere. Having to separately parallelize everything would be a real pain.

Comment: I think `Parallelize` should be able to handle this properly if your `.` has attribute `Flat`, but I'm not 100% sure.  Otherwise try `ParallelCombine[Identity, Unevaluated[expr1.expr2.expr3.expr4]]`.  Search for "associative operations" [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.html).